# Why don't Type.resolveClass and import work for the same class name?

Tags: haxe

Consider the following file named "MyClass.hx".

```
package mypackage;

class MyClass {}

class MySubClass extends MyClass {}
```

When using `MySubClass` in another file, I have to specify the full name of `mypackage.MyClass.MySubClass` or import `mypackage.MyClass`. However, in order to access this type using `Type.resolveClass`, I have to specify `mypackage.MySubClass`, and trying to resolve `mypackage.MyClass.MySubClass` returns null.

I don't understand the difference, can someone help me understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflection API (to which `Type` is a part of) works at run-time, but sub-types exist in different namespaces then and at compile time (for reasons I don't fully understand).

From the [relevant](http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-module-sub-types.html) section of the Haxe Manual:

> The sub-type relation is not reflected at run-time. That is, public sub-types become a member of their containing package, which could lead to conflicts if two modules within the same package tried to define the same sub-type.var e:haxe.macro.Expr.ExprDef;